# Anti Skimmer and Anti fraud?

Tags: banks, atm

Would you please tell me what is the difference between Anti-skimmer and Anti-fraud in ATMs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anti-skimming techniques are just a subset of anti-fraud techniques. Anti-fraud in ATMs is the collection of defense mechanism against payment card fraud. It includes anti-skimming devices, cameras embedded in ATMs, measures to prevent shoulder surfing, etc.

Anti-skimming devices in particular are devices installed on or embedded in the ATM. They prevent the illegitimate copying of the payment card information.